# Transition from left to right using a UITabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, core-animation

Hi guys I am trying to figure out how to transition from left to right (or visa versa) when swiping the screen using my uitabbarcontroller.

This is how far I have got but I am not sure on how to get the transition to work how I need it to :

```
 UIViewController * fromViewController = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
        UIViewController * toViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];

    // set up an animation for the transition between the views
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[[fromViewController view] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"switchToView"];


    CGRect endFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
    CGRect startFrame = endFrame;
    startFrame.origin.x += 320;
    toViewController.view.frame = startFrame;

    // Transition going left and right.
    [UIView transitionFromView:fromViewController.view toView:toViewController.view duration:4.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                       completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                           toViewController.view.frame = endFrame;

                        if (finished) {
                            self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
                        }

                    }];
```

What method can I use to achieve this effect.